# Cocoa UI change

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, user-interface

How can I remove & show new UI controls at one place in mac application.
I want to have some layout at one place..which will be shown in different conditions.
I am new to the Xcode & objective c.
Please help

Comment: You have to be more precise: what is it exactly you'd like to achieve. Put it a simple scenario and place that here.

Comment: Suppose I have one screen with two buttons. I want to navigate to another screen which will be having 3 buttons & line edit. Means I want to navigate between forms. Hiding the previous one showing the other & vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, it sounds like you want something along the lines of a wizard. For that, I'd suggest grouping your forms into an [NSTabView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTabView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can disable the tabs, and call one of the various [tab selection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTabView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000365-SW3) methods instead. Have a look at Apple's [Introduction to Tab Views](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TabView/TabView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000074i) for more.

Comment: thanks for the help...yes I need same as the tab view....may be I can use some technique from here.

Answer (score 1):

See NSView's [-replaceSubview:with:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html)

Answer (score 1):

I found [this example](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/03/03/core-animation-tutorial-wizard-dialog-with-transitions/) pretty helpful. He describes a good way to set up your related views. You can always add the animation later once you get the basics down.

Comment: thanks for the example...its very nice...but I have to try..it..will this one work if I add more UI controls.